# How to fix error in finding absolute error from Euler value and Exact value in Python and Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am learning computer simulation and modeling in Python and jupyter.
The initial population is 100. I need to find population until the time is 100 using time step 8. So, i put initial population as p0 = 100. The timestep should be 8.

i have imported

```
from pylab import *
%matplotlib inline
import math
```

then i wrote a function for finding population using Euler method

```
def eulerPop():
    t = 0
    p0 = 100
    p = p0
    r = 0.1
    dt = 8

    t_array = [0]
    pop_array = [p]

    while t < 100:

        p += (r * p * dt)
        t += dt
        #print (p, t)

        t_array.append(t)
        pop_array.append(p)
    return pop_array,t_array
```

then i printed the value

```
print(eulerPop())
```

it resulted right answer which are as follows

```
([100, 180.0, 324.0, 583.2, 1049.7600000000002, 1889.5680000000004, 3401.2224000000006, 6122.200320000002, 11019.960576000003, 19835.929036800007, 35704.67226624001, 64268.410079232024, 115683.13814261765, 208229.6486567118], [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104])
```

then I wrote another function to find the exact population

```
def exactPop():
    p0 = 100
    t = 0
    dt = 8
    r = 0.1
    p = p0
    t_array = [0]
    pop_array = [p]
    while t < 100:

        p = (p * e ** (0.1 * 8))
        t += dt
        #print (p, t)

        t_array.append(t)
        pop_array.append(p)
    return pop_array,t_array
```

then i printed the outcomes (i got as it should be)

```
([100, 222.55409284924673, 495.3032424395114, 1102.3176380641598, 2453.253019710934, 5459.815003314422, 12151.041751873483, 27042.64074261525, 60184.503787208174, 133943.0764394417, 298095.79870417266, 663424.400627788, 1476478.156557726, 3285962.567444328], [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104])
```

from these function we came to know that p1 = 180 using Euler method but the exact population is 222.55409284924673

hence the difference should give Absolute Error because Absolute Error = Exact - population from Euler Method

However i am not able to create a function for Absolute Error

what is wrong in the following code and how can i fix it?

```
def absEulerError():
    t = 0
    p0 = 100
    p = p0
    r = 0.1
    dt = 8
    t_array = [0]
    pop_array = [p]
    ep = p0

    while t < 100:

        p += ((ep * e ** (0.1 * 8)) - (r * p * dt))
        t += dt
        #print (p, t)

        t_array.append(t)
        pop_array.append(p)
    return pop_array,t_array
```

Thank You

Comment: You already have functions for exact pop and Euler pop. Your formula includes those, so call those methods. Generate a new list with those results

Comment: @cricket_007 I just don't know the way here to generate  the list with my 2 working functions. Could you help me? don't know much with python.

Comment: Check out this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python